# Something wrong with routes

Tags: angular

I'm just learning angular so bear with me.

I have my routes registered as so.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent },
    { path: 'parts', component: PartsComponent },
    { path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent },
    { path: 'service', component: ServiceComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent}

];
```

I then have a constant like this

import { MenuItem } from './MenuItem';

```
export const items: MenuItem[] = [
    { name: 'Welcome to hansen international', url: '/', title: 'Home' },
    { name: 'Contact Us', url: '/contact-us', title: 'Contact Us' },
    { name: 'Parts', url: 'parts', title: 'Parts' },
    { name: 'Sales', url: 'sales', title: 'Sales' },
    { name: 'Service', url: 'service', title: 'Service' }
];
```

In my nav component, I'm doing this

{{i.name}}

The odd thing is, if you click contact us, it works fine. Hwoever, if you click any of the other nav things, it doesn't work on the first try, but then they all work after that no problem. You can click any of them, but you have to click them twice to get them to start working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I posted here and immediately saw the issue. I needed a / in front of them. It's just odd they worked after a second click.